# Initial HTML text field cursor position

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I am facing a weird problem with a text field on my page. This HTML structure is generated by some Java code (which is very cluttered and written years back). The problem I am facing is, when I click on the text field (Highlighted in the snapshot), the cursor positions itself on the second field instead of the very first one. This happens only with this particular column only. I have shared the basic HTML structure of one  of this table (though its cluttered please bear with me).

HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ch/yq4Xb/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
VALUE="&nbsp;"
```

to

```
VALUE=""
```

Comment: Thanks Zod. Let me try it real quick and post the results back.

Comment: @t3ch: Usually, years back, code would put an `&nbsp;` in a table cell if the cell would otherwise be empty, because of some cell border idiocy. That's better handled these days via CSS, but more to the point, it isn't relevant when the cell contains an `input` anyway... So the code wants updating. :-)

Comment: Folks, if you notice the very next text field, that has the same value and cursor starts from the first position.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, as I mentioned this app is written some 10 years back :) , can you comment on my last post.

Comment: @t3ch: Not for me it doesn't. (I had to un-disable the fields in that fiddle, btw, to even be able to click in them.) It depends on where I click. If I click anywhere beyond the *very beginning of the field*, I get it after the space.

Comment: @t3ch . hey i just remove the   VALUE="&nbsp;" disabled  in jsfiddle and its working fine for both text box. 
anymore issues??

Comment: Folks, I just tried on my machine too.. and its working fine. Thanks a lot. One confusion still remains, why it was working for the very next input field, even though the VALUE="$nbsp;" was there.